# Notification on new app version in IOS app store

Tags: ios, applications, notifications

Is there a way to be notified when a new version of an application is published to the app store?

I don't mean the general notification on the app store when opened. I would like to get an email or equivalent as soon as a new version is published in the app store. I need to track the version available in the app store for several applications at once.

Comment: why not use the app store's banner? it shows a red dot if one is available.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this from the App Store.  Developers do not have access to any Apple API to notify users when a new version is available within the App Store.

Developers can notify users **within their own app** that a new version is available.  For example, I have several apps that send me a popup message about a new version but I must open an older version of that app first, before I can see the notification.

Comment: How do I get notfied about my own app, when it is available in the App Store (and synched world wide)?

Comment: @testing The only way I'm aware to do this is to manually release your app in the store (instead of letting Apple put it out when ready).

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would provide a solution:
https://ifttt.com/applets/C24NsQMa

But only for single app, and cannot duplicate IFTTT applet:
https://help.ifttt.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001421514-Can-I-duplicate-an-Applet-

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide **supporting info** as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained and links can change, making your answer incorrect.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review